# problem running .mkv files in ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, mkv

I have been trying to run .mkv files in my ubuntu 14.04 and it says weird things different times, for the last few days it showed some diffrent errors, today it says 
"Can't play a text file without video or visualizations"

How to get rid of this thing, i can't play any video in my laptop

Comment: What do you mean by "run .mkv files"? .mkv files are not supposed to be run!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try opening them using VLC media player, you can find it in the Software Center, or another video player.

Comment: Can you explain more detail?

Comment: Install VLC Media player, and try to open the file.
sudo apt-get install vlc